# How to import jQuery typing for angular2 seed?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I'm failing to integrate jQuery typings into an [anguler2-seed](https://mgechev.github.io/angular2-seed/) project.

In my component I'm using jQuery like this:

```
declare let $: any;

export class LeafletComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.popup = $(this.element.nativeElement).find('#leaflet-popup');
    }
}
```

This works fine, but leaves me with an untyped `$` object. I'd prefer to have something like:

```
declare let $: JQueryStatic;
```

I installed [@types/jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery) with npm and tried to use `JQueryStatic`. I also tried all sorts of import statements to get a `$` object. Nothing worked.

Further more [@types/jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery) only provieds jQuery 2.x types. But I'm actually using jQuery 3.x.

Any ideas how to get proper types for jQuery are preferred for version 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was running into the same issue. I found a solution, let me know if this helps.

in `tools/config/project.config.ts`

add this to the constructor:

```js
this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV.paths[ 'jquery' ] =
 `${this.APP_BASE}node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery`;

this.SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.packages[ 'jquery' ] = {
 main: 'jquery.js',
 defaultExtension: 'js'
};
```

Then, all you need to do is add `import 'jquery';` to `app/app.module.ts`

I also have `"@types/jquery": "^2.0.32"` and `"jquery": "^3.1.1"` in my package.json.

I did not need to declare anything, it just works. I hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

OP - with angular2 seed project, all you need to do is import it like this.

import * as $ from 'jquery';

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you please elaborate?